# How do I convert an uppercase character to an ASCII value in Java?

Tags: java, ascii

Apologies, very new to this.

My task is to create an ASCII convertor wherein the user provides an uppercase character, and it is converted to an ASCII value. It also returns the lowercase equivalent. I'm still on the first step, because I'm not sure how to do it, and even from watching a few videos I'm not too sure. Each time I run the code and enter an uppercase character, it always returns 65. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CharConvertor
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      char character = 'A';
      int ascii = (int) character; 
      
      System.out.println("Please enter an uppercase character: ");
      character = input.next().charAt(0); // Allows user to choose an uppercase character
      System.out.println(character+" in ASCII is "+ascii+".");    
      
    }

}
```

I thought 'A' would be like a placeholder for any letter, but that didn't work, and it returned 65 each time. I also tried to just do *char character;*, but I just received an error message saying it was not initialized.

Comment: The reason you get the same value each time is because your `ascii` variable is assigned *before* user input and is not changed thereafter

Comment: `=` is assignment, which happens when the statement is executed.  It is not some sort of declaration of mathematical identity, such that 'ascii' will always depend on the current value of 'character'.

Comment: Even if fixed, your code will not necessarily produce ASCII values, it will produce UTF-16 codepoint values, only Unicode codepoints 0 - 127 (U+0000 - U+007F) are also ASCII, all codepoints beyond that are not ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to calculate and print ASCII value for input(character).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CharConvertor
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      char character = 'A';
      
      System.out.println("Please enter an uppercase character: ");
      character = input.next().charAt(0); // Allows user to choose an uppercase character
      System.out.println(character+" in ASCII is "+((int) character )+".");    
      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the Character class methods.  This also enforces the input requirements.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String str;
System.out.print("Please enter an uppercase character: ");

//Allows user to choose an uppercase character
while((str = input.next()).length() != 1 || Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(0))) {
     System.out.print("Please enter a single uppercase character: ");
}   
System.out.println(str.charAt(0)+" in ASCII is "+ Character.codePointAt(str, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```java
String input = scanner.nextLine();  // Gather input from user.

int codePoint = input.codePointAt( 0 );  // Get code point (ASCII code) for first character of input.
String upper = Character.toString( codePoint );  // Convert back to a `String` textual object.

int codePointOfLowercase = Character.toLowerCase( codePoint );  // Get the code point (ASCII code) of the partner lowercase character.
String lower = Character.toString( codePointOfLowercase );  // Generate a `String` textual object containing that lowercase letter.

System.out.println( "You entered uppercase letter: " + upper + " which has a code point of: " + codePoint + "." );  // Dump to console.
System.out.println( "The matching lowercase character is: " + lower + ", code point: " + codePointOfLowercase + "." );
```

## Write super-simple code

You are combining functions within a single line of code. Debugging your app is generally made easier if you restrict each line to a single operation.

Also, super simple code happens to be easiest for a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) to optimize at runtime.

Another benefit is that short sweet lines provide an opportunity to name results with an explanatory name. This makes your code more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).

So notice in example code below how we accomplish one step at a time, one line at a time.

## Code point

Other Answers are correct. However, those Answers and your Question use the legacy type `char`.

As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. The `char` type and its wrapper class `Character` have been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5.

Instead, make a habit of using [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

```
String input = "A" ; 
int codePoint = input.codePointAt( 0 );
```

Unicode is a superset of US-ASCII. So the first 128 code points (0-127) are indeed the ASCII codes you requested.

Test if the input is a letter:

```
if( Character.isLetter( codePoint ) ) {
    … 
} else { … reject user’s input }
```

Test if the input is uppercase:

```
if( Character.isUpperCase( codePoint ) ) { … } else { … reject user’s input }
```

Convert the code point back to text.

```
String upper = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
```

Get the lowercase partner for that uppercase letter.

```
int codePointOfLowercase = Character.toLowerCase( codePoint ) ;
String lower = Character.toString( codePointOfLowercase ) ;
```

Be aware that not all languages have the notion of upper and lower case.

### Example code

Here is an entire example app.

```java
package work.basil.example.text;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UpperLower
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println( "Enter an uppercase letter A-Z, from basic English/Latin alphabet:" );

        String input = scanner.nextLine();  // Read user input
        int codePoint = input.codePointAt( 0 );
        if ( Character.isLetter( codePoint ) )
        {
            if ( Character.isUpperCase( codePoint ) )
            {
                String upper = Character.toString( codePoint );
                int codePointOfLowercase = Character.toLowerCase( codePoint );
                String lower = Character.toString( codePointOfLowercase );
                System.out.println( "You entered uppercase letter: " + upper + " which has a code point of: " + codePoint + "." );
                System.out.println( "The matching lowercase character is: " + lower + ", code point: " + codePointOfLowercase + "." );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "Oops, the letter you entered was not uppercase. Program ending. " );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( "Oops, you entered something other than a letter, such as a digit or punctuation. Program ending. " );
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

```
A
You entered uppercase letter: A which has a code point of: 65.
The matching lowercase character is: a, code point: 97.
```